# Redirect customer to App proxy url on clicking checkout button

Tags: shopify, redirect, checkout

I am working on a Shopify app which contains the custom checkout page. I achieved it by using [app proxy](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/application-proxies). Now I need to redirect the customer to app custom checkout URL when the customer will click on the checkout button. I couldn't find any solution to achieve this. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Calling an App Proxy, that is, making a request to your App Proxy is simple. It is a GET or POST. So when your customer clicks the button, your event listener can process it, and trigger a GET or POST.

Your App Proxy can send back JSON or Liquid, and from there, you decide the flow of the App.